# Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11 when set attributedString

Tags: swift, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I am doing something like this `lbl.attributedText = self.commonData[(addedArray[0])]![indexPath.row+1]["post_title"] as? String`

Then my app crash and give me an error message like

```
Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11
```

What is the reason for this? And how to solve this?
Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Oh god!! why you are making it too complex? Check what property you are setting with what type of value (`attributedText as? String`)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is so long that compiler can't compile it. Just separate it.